# Run Integration Tests agains a running Server

Tags: testing, grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

How to run Grails integration tests against a running server?

I've searched the web but the advices date to 2010 and Grail 1.3.x...

Answer (score 0):

Grails 3 Integration test will run against a running server.  You need to define a test environment application.yml and add the @Integration annotation to your class.

```
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import spock.lang.Specification

@Integration
class LookupServiceIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    def lookupService

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test database connection"() {

        when:
        def row = lookupService.testMethod()

        then:
        println("Row one = "+row.one)
        row.one == 1
    }
}
```

Here is a simple example service:

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import groovy.sql.Sql

@Transactional
class LookupService {

    def dataSource

    def testMethod() {
        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.firstRow("SELECT 1 AS one")
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer. But how do I attach the to an application running e.g. on `localhost:8080`?

Comment: Your talking about Functional Tests not Integration Tests.

Comment: I'm talking about both the tests. In Grails functional tests are technically integration tests too as they are also annotated with `@Integration`... but big thank for trying to help me. :D Maybe I should generalize my question: "How can I run any code agains a running Grails server?". Do you see what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your looking for Functional Tests not Integration Tests.  Grails 3 added better support for Functional Tests.  See Link Below.

[Grails 3 Functional Tests](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-functional-test.html)